# xdotool - how do I select text using shift+Home or shift+End?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xdotool

I'm trying to get text selection working the way I want on my laptop using Ubuntu 16.04. I don't have home/end keys on my laptop, so I installed xdotool and using the keyboard settings I mapped `Super+left` to `xdotool getactivewindow key Home` and `Super+right` to `xdotool getactivewindow key End`.

This is working as expected. However, I'd also like to have `Shift+Super+Left`  select text from my cursor to the beginning of the line, and similarly `Shift+Super+Right` select to the end of the line. I tried mapping these combinations to xdotool using `xdotool getactivewindow key shift+Home` but this doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried running `sleep 4 && xdotool key shift+Home` in a terminal and then switching to my text editor, and it seems like only the `Home` key is firing - no text is selected. So it seems like a xdotool problem and not my keyboard. Does anyone know the proper key combination for xdotool to select text to the beginning/end of a line?

**Update:**

Running`sleep 4 && xdotool key Shift+Home` with a capital **S** for shift works. Text is highlighted in my text editor from my cursor to the beginning of the line. However, it's still not working as a shortcut even with a capital S. So now I'm thinking there is something else wrong with the way I'm inputting the xdotool command into Ubuntu's keyboard settings.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to select the line? Is a triple-click an option?

Comment: Here goes a resource for you https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/plain/keysymdef.h

Comment: In my experience, Xdotool is not good for complex keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @wjandrea are there better options for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @wjandrea nevermind, I installed Autokey and managed to get it working using that.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
xdotool keyup Shift+Super+Left key shift+Home
```

The keyup statement will release the hotkey you are pressing before simulating pressing the key combination shift+Home.

Answer (score 2):

In order to bind Shift+Home/End together with **xdotool**, please use:

```
xdotool key --window '$(xdotool getactivewindow)' Shift+Home

xdotool key --window '$(xdotool getactivewindow)' Shift+End
```

Then, you can customize your shortcut by `Shift+Alt+Right Arrow` and `Shift+Alt+Left Arrow`.

Comment: Also: `xdotool getactivewindow key Shift+Home`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this working with xdotool, I ended up installing Autokey. I got it to work by creating a phrase with the following command: `<shift>+<home>` and mapping to the hotkey I wanted. I made a similar one for `<shift>+<end>`.

Comment: +1 to autokey, maybe not the best/exact answer to original question... but i can't live without it!